# Expected values of two non-negative, integer-valued random variables related to an urn problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, st.statistics

Consider an urn containing $c$ distinguishable balls, $\alpha$ of which are red, $\beta$ of which are blue, and $\gamma$ of which are green, and $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=c$. We assume $\alpha,\beta,\gamma>0$.

We introduce the non-negative, integer-valued random variable $X$, defined as "the number of independent trials (i.e. with replacement) needed to get at least one red ball and at least one blue ball", and the non-negative, integer-valued random variable $Y$, defined as "the number of independent trials needed to get at least one red ball and at least one blue ball and at least one green ball".

> What are the expected values of $X$ and $Y$?

**My attempt:**

The solution for the case of the variable $X$, as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2770750), is based on the fact that the probability to get at least one red ball and at least one blue ball, in $i$ independent trials, is

$$
P(L_{1,1}^{A,B};i)=1-\left(\frac{\alpha+\gamma}{c}\right)^i-\left(\frac{\beta+\gamma}{c}\right)^i+\left(\frac{\gamma}{c}\right)^i.
$$

Since $X$ is a non-negative and integer-valued variable, its expected value $E[X]$can be written as

$$E[X]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(X>i).$$

However, $P(X>i)=1-P(L_{1,1}^{A,B};i)$. Therefore, since we are dealing with the geometric series,
$$
E[X]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left[ \left(\frac{\alpha+\gamma}{c}\right)^i+\left(\frac{\beta+\gamma}{c}\right)^i-\left(\frac{\gamma}{c}\right)^i\right]=\frac{c}{\beta}+\frac{c}{\alpha}-\frac{c}{\alpha+\beta}.
$$

My problem here is: Are we correctly considering the fact that the event $L_{1,1}^{A,B}$ cannot occur at the first trial?

I would say "yes", and I am generally confident on this result, but I cannot really extend this reasoning to the variable $Y$.

My solution for the variable $Y$, following this suggestion, would be the following: The probability to get at least one red ball and at least one blue ball and at least one green ball, always in $i$ trials, is $$P(L_{1,1,1}^{A,B,G};i)=1-\left(\frac{\alpha+\gamma}{c}\right)^i-\left(\frac{\beta+\gamma}{c}\right)^i-\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{c}\right)^i+\left(\frac{\alpha}{c}\right)^i+\left(\frac{\beta}{c}\right)^i+\left(\frac{\gamma}{c}\right)^i$$.

Since, again, $Y$ is a non-negative, integer-valued random variable, 
$$E[Y]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(Y>i).$$

And, again, since  $P(Y>i)=1-P(L_{1,1,1}^{A,B,G};i)$, and applying again the property of the sum of the geometric series,
$$
E[Y]=\frac{c}{\beta}+\frac{c}{\alpha}+\frac{c}{\gamma}-\frac{c}{\alpha+\beta}-\frac{c}{\alpha+\gamma}-\frac{c}{\beta+\gamma}.
$$

The problem I mentioned before appears here more evident: what about the case of $i=0,1,2$? Is the index $i$ correctly treated in the expression of $E[Y]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(Y>i)$?

As observed in this other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2865474), I would say "no". But then I do not understand how to deal also with the index $i$ in the expression $E[X]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(X>i)$.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** A further question:

> Since we can extract at least once a ball of each of the three colors only if we have already extracted at least once two balls of two different colors, is it correct to assess $E[Y]≥E[X]+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $j=1,2,3$, let $p_j$ denote the probability of getting a red, blue, green ball (respectively) in one trial. Let $(p,q,r):=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$, so that $p+q+r=1$. 
For $x=0,1,\dots$ and $j=1,2,3$, let $N_{x,j}$ denote the number of trials with outcome $j$ among the first $x$ trials. Then for $x=0,1,\dots$ 
\begin{align}
 P(X>x)&=P(N_{x,1}=0\text{ or }N_{x,2}=0) \\ 
 &=P(N_{x,1}=0)+P(N_{x,2}=0)-P(N_{x,1}=0\text{ and }N_{x,2}=0) \\
 &=(q+r)^x+(p+r)^x-r^x
\end{align}
and similarly
\begin{align}
 P(Y>x)&=P(N_{x,1}=0\text{ or }N_{x,2}=0\text{ or }N_{x,3}=0) \\ 
 &=(q+r)^x+(p+r)^x+(p+q)^x-r^x-q^x-p^x+0^x,
\end{align}
with $0^0:=1$.

Thus, 
\begin{equation}
 EX=\sum_{x=0}^\infty P(X>x)=\frac1p+\frac1q-\frac1{p+q}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
 EY=\sum_{x=0}^\infty P(Y>x)=\frac1p+\frac1q+\frac1r-\frac1{q+r}-\frac1{p+r}-\frac1{p+q}+1. 
\end{equation}
It seem that your answer for $EY$ misses the summand $1$.

Comment: Thank you Iosif! I am studying your answer only now. Sorry for late reply. I'll come back to you soon!

Comment: Yes. I think this solves my doubts. Thanks again! A further question: Since we can extract at least once the three colors only if we have already extracted at least once two colors, is it correct to assess $EY\geq EX+1$?

Comment: @AndreaPrunotto : Concerning your latter comment: This reasoning would be incorrect in general, because one can get at least two colors of the three faster (or even much faster, depending on $p,q,r$), than both the red and blue ones. The conclusion $EY\ge EX+1$ will not hold in general either, when $p$ and $q$ are small enough as compared with $r$; e.g., compare the expressions for $EX$ and $EY$ for $p=q=r/2$.

Comment: Thanks again, Iosif. I am thinking about your observation.

Comment: Sure. Your example is illuminating. I still have some difficulties with some aspects of this problem, but I will post another question maybe.

Comment: The final expression for $E\,Y$ might be prettier (and the extension to more colours more obvious) if the $+1$ was written $+\dfrac1{p+q+r}$

Comment: @IosifPinelis Please, can you have a look to this https://mathoverflow.net/q/321964/124302 and possibly explain me what I'm doing wrong there? Thanks!