# Expected values of two random variables related to a simple urn problem

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

In an urn there are $u$ balls, $b$ of which are black.

If we perform $n$ trials of one ball at a time with replacement, the probability of the event $E$ to get $n$ times a black ball is $P(E)=\left(\frac{b}{u}\right)^n$, whereas the probability of the event $L$ to get at least one black ball is $P(L)=1-\left(\frac{u-b}{u}\right)^n$.

Let $X$ be the non-negative, integer-valued random variable representing the number of trials it takes to get a success for the event $E$, and $Y$ the  non-negative, integer-valued random variable  representing the number of trials it takes to get a success for the event $L$.

> **What are the expected values $\mathbb{E}[X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y]$?**

My attempt for  $\mathbb{E}[X]$:

I denote with $P(E;k)$ the probability to get a success for the event $E$ at the trial $k$.

The variable $X$ can assume only the value $n$, therefore, by definition it should be $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{k=1}^n k P(E;k)=\sum_{k=1}^n k P(E)\delta_{n,k}=nP(E).$$

My attempt for  $\mathbb{E}[Y]$:

I denote with $P(L;k)$ the probability to get a success for the event $L$ at the trial $k$.

The variable $Y$ can assume any value from $1$ to $n$, therefore, by definition, it should be 
$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\sum_{k=1}^n k P(L;k)=\sum_{k=1}^n k \left[1-\left(\frac{u-b}{u}\right)^k\right].$$

Are these calculations correct?

Comment: If I understand your question (the desription does not make much sense for me), the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are geometrically distributed. These random variables are not bounded by $n$, so your calculations cannot be correct. Please google for geometric distribution.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Thanks for your comment.

Comment: In your definitions of of $X$ and $Y$, what do you mean by "trials" and "a success for the event"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Suppose that I bet to get at least one black ball in $n=10$ trials (event $L$). I extract $1,2\ldots k$ balls from the urn. If at the trial $k=3$ I get a black ball, I have already won the bet, no matter the following trials. This means that the trial $k=3$ was successful for the event $L$, and $Y=3$

Comment: The definitions of $X$ and $Y$ are still unclear. In particular, what will be the value of $X$ if none of the first $n$ balls is black? More generally, can you define $Y$ and $Y$ formally, without using terms such as "trials", "bets", "winning", etc.?

Comment: @IosifPinelis We have $n$ attempts. $X$ is the number of times I should draw a ball from the urn in order to get $n$ black balls. $Y$ is the number of times I should draw a ball from the urn in order to get at least one black ball. In the first case, I always need to do $X=n$ attempts, and the probability that all the balls are black is $P(X=n)=\frac{b^n}{u^n}$. In the second case, I can do $Y=\{1,2,3\ldots n\}$ attempts, because in all these cases I have a probability to get at least one black ball, which is $P(Y=k)=1-\frac{(u-b)^k}{u^k}$. Is this ill posed?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your definitions. Perhaps you can state them in purely formal terms (such as independent identically distributed random variables, with certain distributions) and completely eschew such non-mathematical terms as "draw", "attempt", "trials", etc.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I see. I'm sorry if I couldn't be more clear. Maybe I can do the other way round, i.e. to tell you (in non-mathematical terms) what I am looking for, and then you can help me to formulate better the question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Among the $n$ trials, one and only one of them can be the one in which the event $E$ occurs. Well, that trial can be only the last one! Therefore, if we denote with $X$ the number of trials needed to get $n$ black balls, well $X$ can be only equal to $n$. What is the probability that this $n$-th trials is the one related to the extraction of exactly $n$ black balls, out of $u$? Welll, $\frac{b^n}{u^n}$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis A similar approach (sorry if it is not well stated) applies for the other event. Among the  $n$ trials, each of them can be the one in which the event "to get at least one black ball" occurs. Which trial? Randomly, any among $Y=1,2,\ldots n$. What is the probability to get at least one black ball at the $k$-th trial? Well, it is $1-\frac{(u-b)^n}{u^n}$. I would say that this is $P(Y=k)$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $P(Y=k)=1-\frac{(u-b)^k}{u^k}$.

Comment: if, as you say, _the variable $X$ can assume only the value $$_, then how can its expected value be any different from $n$?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker True. The obscure point (for me) is that $X=n$ does not occur with probability $1$. I thought that, since $X=k$ occurs with $P(X=k)=0$ for each $k\neq n$, and $X=n$ with $P(X=n)=\frac{b^n}{c^n}$, then we could use the distribution of $P(X)$ to define the expected value. I understand that something is wrong here, but I don't see exactly where.

Comment: I'm afraid the question as phrased has no answer; a different question does: "Repeatedly draw a ball with replacement, stop when you have $n$ black balls. What is the expected number of balls drawn?" --- is that a question that would interest you?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Yes, maybe this is a better approach. How can I proceed, then? Can I use a similar approach for the other event? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For the alternative approach in the comments, the [Pascal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) applies: Repeatedly draw a ball with replacement from an urn with $u$ balls, $b$ of which are black, stop when you have $n$ black balls. Let $X$ be the number of balls drawn. The probability distribution of $X$ is
$$P(X=N)=\binom{N-1}{n-1} (b/u)^{n}(1-b/u)^{N-n},\;\;N\geq n,$$
with expectation value $\mathbb{E}(X)=nu/b$.

Comment: Thanks Carlo, it looks really neat! Please, can you help me to apply the same approach to the other event?

Comment: For event $Y$ the best I can come up with is to ask for the number of draws until the first black ball, which has expectation value $u/b$.

Answer (score 0):

In your definitions, you have confused:

$$P(E;k)$$

This actually means:

$$P(X=k|E)$$

(which equals $\delta_{kn}$ and gives the correct value that $\mathbb E(X)=n$).

and not, as you have used:

$$P(E|X=k)$$

which equals $P(E)\delta_{kn}$.

See [Conditional Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) for more information.